# paperclip custom path and url for polymorphic associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

I am using attachment model as polymorphic association. How to change path and url parameters based on the associations.

Attachment Model

```
class Attachment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :attachable, :polymorphic => true

  has_attached_file :attachment,
                    :url  => "/attachments/:id/:basename.:extension",
                    :path => ":rails_root/public/attachments/:id/:basename.:extension",
                    :default_url => "/attachments/original/no-file.txt"
end
```

Project Model

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
 ...
 has_many :attachments, :as => :attachable, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

Client

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
 ...
 has_many :attachments, :as => :attachable, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

following path files are saving fine.

```
:path => ":rails_root/public/attachments/:id/:basename.:extension",
```

but I need to save files based on association like, for this how do pass the parameters to 'path'. 'attachable_type' defines the which association upload file belongs

```
/attachments/project/
/attachments/client/
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [Paperclip Interpolations](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/wiki/Interpolations). Interpolations allows you to call a method to determine the value of a part of the path.

```
class Attachment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :attachable, :polymorphic => true

  Paperclip.interpolates :attached_to do |attachment, style|
    attachment.instance.attachable.class.to_s.downcase
  end

  has_attached_file :attachment,
                    :url  => "/attachments/:id/:basename.:extension",
                    :path => ":rails_root/public/attachments/:attached_to/:id/:basename.:extension",
                    :default_url => "/attachments/original/no-file.txt"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
has_attached_file :attachment, :path => ":rails_root/public/attachments/#{lambda { |a| a.instance.images_path? ? 'project' : 'client' }}/:id/:basename.:extension"



def images_path?
    if your pretty condition  
      #return true
    else
      #return false 
    end
  end
```